# python: populating tuples in tuples over dataframe range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 4 portfolios a,b,c,d which can take on values either "no" or "own" over a period of time. (code included below to facilitate replication)

```
ano=('a','no',datetime(2018,1,1), datetime(2018,1,2))
aown=('a','own',datetime(2018,1,3), datetime(2018,1,4))
bno=('b','no',datetime(2018,1,1), datetime(2018,1,5))
bown=('b','own',datetime(2018,1,6), datetime(2018,1,7))
cown=('c','own',datetime(2018,1,9), datetime(2018,1,10))
down=('d','own',datetime(2018,1,9), datetime(2018,1,9))

sch=pd.DataFrame([ano,aown,bno,bown,cown,down],columns=['portf','base','st','end'])
```

Summary of schedule:

```
    portf   base    st          end
0   a       no      2018-01-01  2018-01-02
1   a       own     2018-01-03  2018-01-04
2   b       no      2018-01-01  2018-01-05
3   b       own     2018-01-06  2018-01-07
4   c       own     2018-01-09  2018-01-10
5   d       own     2018-01-09  2018-01-09
```

What I have tried: create a holding dataframe and filling in values based on the schedule. Unfortunately the first portfolio 'a' gets overridden

```
df=pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(min(sch.st),max(sch.end)),columns=['portf','base'])
for row in range(len(sch)):
        df.loc[sch['st'][row]:sch['end'][row],['portf','base']]= sch.loc[row,['portf','base']].values

            portf   base
2018-01-01  b       no
2018-01-02  b       no
2018-01-03  b       no
2018-01-04  b       no
2018-01-05  b       no
2018-01-06  b       own
2018-01-07  b       own
2018-01-08  NaN     NaN
2018-01-09  d       own
2018-01-10  c       own
```

desired output:

```
2018-01-01  (('a','no'), ('b','no'))
2018-01-02  (('a','no'), ('b','no'))
2018-01-03  (('a','own'), ('b','no'))
2018-01-04  (('a','own'), ('b','no'))
2018-01-05  ('b','no')
...
```

I am sure there's an easier way of achieving this but probably this is an example I haven't encountered before. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the starting columns in the desired output ?

Comment: Do you really need the output in a Series that contains tuple of tuples? This is typically not advised for pandas.

Comment: hi ALollz, i think i can work without tuples of tuples. thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would organize the data differently, index is date, columns for portf and the values are base.

First we need to reshape the data and resample to daily fields. Then it's a simple pivot.

```
cols = ['portf', 'base']
s = (df.reset_index()
       .melt(cols+['index'], value_name='date')
       .set_index('date')
       .groupby(cols+['index'], group_keys=False)
       .resample('D').ffill()
       .drop(columns=['variable', 'index'])
       .reset_index())

res = s.pivot(index='date', columns='portf')
res = res.resample('D').first()  # Recover missing dates between
```

#### Output `res`

```
           base               
portf         a    b    c    d
2018-01-01   no   no  NaN  NaN
2018-01-02   no   no  NaN  NaN
2018-01-03  own   no  NaN  NaN
2018-01-04  own   no  NaN  NaN
2018-01-05  NaN   no  NaN  NaN
2018-01-06  NaN  own  NaN  NaN
2018-01-07  NaN  own  NaN  NaN
2018-01-08  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2018-01-09  NaN  NaN  own  own
2018-01-10  NaN  NaN  own  NaN
```

---

If you need your other output, we can get there with some less than ideal `Series.apply` calls. This will be very bad for a large DataFrame; I would seriously consider keeping the above.

```
s.set_index('date').apply(tuple, axis=1).groupby('date').apply(tuple)

date
2018-01-01      ((a, no), (b, no))
2018-01-02      ((a, no), (b, no))
2018-01-03     ((a, own), (b, no))
2018-01-04     ((a, own), (b, no))
2018-01-05              ((b, no),)
2018-01-06             ((b, own),)
2018-01-07             ((b, own),)
2018-01-09    ((c, own), (d, own))
2018-01-10             ((c, own),)
dtype: object
```